# WCF Error After Hosting In cloud server

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have Create asp.net web application with serivce reference that hosted in cloud server. When I'm Running asp.net application on Visual studio it runs With out any error.But when I Host it in cloud server I got an error
"There was no endpoint listening at URl that could accept the message"
Hear is the Endpoint configuration of the wcf web service

```html
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="NewStandardEndpoint0" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService3.Service1">
        <endpoint address="Service1.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          name="sample" contract="WcfService3.IService1" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And hear is it for client application

```html
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://teamaaa-001-site1.smarterasp.net/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your protocol mapping section. You have https there instead of http. Everything else is http.

```
<add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="http" />
```

Add:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://teamaaa-001-site1.smarterasp.net/Service1.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I changed protocole mapping o http .but problem remain same .do I need to do some change in client application's web config . I can aceess service while client appication running on visual studio.

Comment: Does your whole config section look like my add above?